# How to annotate the objects and the relations between the objects in images?

Tags: relationship, object-detection

Like the visual relationship detection dataset, i want to build my own dataset to train. So how to annotate the objects and the relations between the objects in images? I know the LabeiImg tool to annotate the objects in images, but is there any tool to also annotate the relationship between the objects? The VRD dataset (https://cs.stanford.edu/people/ranjaykrishna/vrd/) Thanks for reply!

Comment: It looks like what you are looking for is - https://www.tensorflow.org/neural_structured_learning

Comment: Thanks for reply! However, it doesn't seem like what i want. I want to build a dataset like VRD dataset, so i need a label tool to annotate the objects and the relationships like <car-behind-tree>. Still, thanks for reply!